# How to Check System.FormatException in OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, system.data.oracleclient

I am calling an oracle stored procedure from my C# code using OracleDataReader. My code is similar as follows

```
OracleDataReader myReader;

if (myReader.HasRow)
{
    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        if (!myReader.IsDBNull(0))
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[0].ToString())
            if (!myReader.IsDBNull(1))
                int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[1].ToString())
    }
}
```

Sometimes the objects myReader[0] and (myReader[1] showing an exception "System.FormatException: No digits found"

If the above exception is happened, I need to assign a default values to the variables num1 and num2. How can I check if myReader[0] and myReader[1] has valid values or not?

Comment: Your check should be for opposite `if(!myReader.IsDBNull(0))`, otherwise  your are trying to convert `DBNull.Value` to `int`

Comment: sorry for the typo. I have updated my question.

Comment: In that case, define `num1` and `num2` before your `if` statement, assign them some default values and then your check and statement could be : `if (!myReader.IsDBNull(0)) num1 = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[0].ToString());`

Comment: Without knowing what the type of myReader[0] and myReader[1] are, there's really not much anyone can suggest other than to catch the exception and do something you need.  e.g. if myReader is a string, and it's empty, you'll have no digits and a format exception.  If you provide more detail, someone might be able to suggest something better for, so far unknown, circumstances.

Comment: Thanks to all, I will try your suggestions and post my result .